# Hsqldb reopen server catalog after SHUTDOWN

Tags: hsqldb

I create an arbitrary number of catalogs (let's say 50) like this:

```
    ...
    properties = new HsqlProperties();
    properties.setProperty("server.remote_open", false);
    properties.setProperty("server.shutdown", false);

    for(int i=0;i<50; i++){
        properties.setProperty("server.database." + i, "file:db/production/pr" + i + "/pr");
        properties.setProperty("server.dbname." + i, "alias" + i);
    }

    Server server = new Server();
    server.setProperties(p);
    server.setLogWriter(null);
    server.setErrWriter(null);
    server.start();
    ...
```

I can successfully connect to each of the created catalogs using username "SA", empty password and the generated alias.
If I issue a 'SHUTDOWN' on one of the opened catalogs, it shuts down correctly but when I try to reopen it I obtain "General error: database alias does not exist", so I need to shut down the whole Server and restart.
How can I reopen the single database after a 'SHUTDOWN' without restarting the Server?

Comment: What code do you use to reopen the database?

Comment: @fredt No code, I want the databases to be accessible from third party applications. Basically I launch my server code in Intellij Idea, then use Libreoffice Base or Netbeans database browser to work on the databases.I can successfully open the databases with both programs, but after issuing a "SHUTDOWN" if I retry opening the database I get "General error: database alias does not exist".

Answer (score 0):

Start the server with the server.remote_open=true property and specify the paths on the connection URL.

http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/listeners-chapt.html#lsc_remote_open

Comment: I need the clients to connect to one of the databases I have prepared for them (with custom roles, users and content). Using server.remote_open=true every client can create a new database at will. I did explore this path, but I did not find a way of disabling arbitrary database creation.

Comment: So you shouldn't allow the clients to perform SHUTDOWN. The clients should connect as a user without admin privileges.

Comment: Agreed, but whenever I want to backup one database of my array of catalogs, I need to shut it down. How do i bring it back online? with server.remote_open=false it seems like the only option is to reboot the whole Server, while with server.remote_open=true I can't avoid malicious or wrongful clients to create arbitrary catalogs.

Comment: The remote_open should be OK if the user doesn't have admin. They may create a database by connecting but they won't be able to log-on and create tables etc.

Comment: If the databases are small, you can make a backup with the SCRIPT command. Or use the BACKUP command for databases of any size.